List of Members of an AppRole of an Application
My organization uses Azure and we have an authentication scheme based on Microsoft Entra.  I own an application that has many approles configured to it and we assign those approles as requiredResourceAccess to other applications.
Using the Microsoft Graph API (REST), I can see the list of approles my application has via:
v1.0/applications(appId='')/appRoles
and I can see which of those approles a specific (& known) application has assigned to it via:
v1.0/applications(appId='')/requiredResourceAccess
What I need to be able to do for support and auditing purposes, is to be able to get a list of the applications that have been assigned to one of the approles of my application.  I know the ID of my application and the ID of all my approles.  How do I get the list of assignments, preferably via the Microsoft Graph API?

You can list appRoleAssignments granted for a service principal
GET /v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='{appId}')/appRoleAssignedTo

this will return all service principals that have been granted any app-only permissions to your application.
Example for the Graph API with appId 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
GET /v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000')/approleAssignedTo

Response
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals('00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000')/appRoleAssignedTo",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "xxx",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "appRoleId": "9a5d68dd-52b0-4cc2-bd40-abcf44ac3a30",
            "createdDateTime": "2024-09-17T06:38:12.2673319Z",
            "principalDisplayName": "contosoapp",
            "principalId": "25abdecb-1234-85bd-2468-12344321795c",
            "principalType": "ServicePrincipal",
            "resourceDisplayName": "Microsoft Graph",
            "resourceId": "3c4020a9-f9ce-4790-ba8f-4f85b0ff62d5"
        }
    ]
}

principalId is the id of a service principal being granted the app role.
appRoleId is the id for the app role that's assigned to the service principal.
